# Angular2 innerHtml binding breaks data binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-databinding

I am trying to bind to innerHtml while keeping data binding. This does not work (outputs {{myVar}}).

```
@Component({
  selector: "test",
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml]="myHtml"></div>
  `,
})
export class TestComponent{
  title = "My Title";
  myHtml: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
    this.myHtml = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<h1>{{title}}</h1>");
  }
}
```

In my real app, myHtml is the content of an SVG file (which is why I need to `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`) and often changes, so that I cannot put it in my template (it could come from 20 different SVG files).

If there was a way to dynamically set the templateUrl for the component, it would also solve my problem, but after searching for quite a while it does not seem possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular2 doesn't process HTML added dynamically, therefore `{{}}`, `[]`, `()`, ... isn't supposed to work. 
Also no components or directives are created, even when HTML added this way matches their selectors.

Only markup added statically to components template are processed.

[Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960) demonstrates an approach if you really need it.

Comment: Your link seems to be what I was looking for, thanks (for this and the hundred other Angular2 questions you've answered and that helped me)