# trying to display string as HTML

Tags: angular, templates

I am trying to display a string as HTML and have it be able to execute like template code.  Ultimately the string comes from the backend.  Here is a [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzgd7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that shows my different attempts.

Can this be done in Angular (using 6)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 innerHtml binding breaks data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40279899/1009922).

Comment: You found ways to display the HTML correctly. The problem is that the Angular bindings cannot be processed  when HTML code is inserted with `[innerHTML]`, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40280167/1009922).

Comment: You may find a few ideas in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

Hello try bt using `[innerHtml]`

*Edited*

**HTML**

```
<div #divref [innerHTML]="html4"></div>
```

**component**

```
  html4 = 'click <a><b>here</b></a>';
  @ViewChild("divref", {read: ElementRef}) divref: ElementRef;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // child is set

   this.divref.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      this.reset();
    })    

  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyyngc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yes, I am using it and the sanitzer in my various examples.  See the stack blitz code.  Not finding much luck.  :-(

Comment: ready, take a look to this code.  inside of `[innerHTML]` you can not include script even if you use **DomSanitizer** you will no have access to the context just **javascript** functions, this example get the element reference and add the click event to the element

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: did you fixed it?

Comment: Well sort of.  I am changing our code so we are not relying on the equivalent of $compile trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize your HTML using the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) class before displaying the HTML. This is a built-in way to get around Angular's security against XSS.